# Is it legal to expand non-type parameter pack to define internal class template with non-type template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, non-type

The minimal code I was able to generate to reproduce the problem:

```
template <int>
struct Tag { };

Tag<0> w;

template <int... Is>
struct Outer {
   template <Tag<Is> &...>
   struct Inner {
   };
};

int main() {
   Outer<0>::Inner<w> f;
}
```

g++ (version 6.1.1 20160511) encounters following error while compiling the code:

> ```
> pp.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
> pp.cc:14:21: internal compiler error: unexpected expression ‘Is’ of kind template_parm_index
>     Outer<0>::Inner<w> f;
> ```

And produces long and boring stack trace. clang++ in version 3.6.0 does not seem to have any problem with compiling the code. The same code with type template parameters compiles just fine in both compilers:

```
template <class>
struct Tag { };

Tag<int> w;

template <class... Ts>
struct Outer {
   template <Tag<Ts> &...>
   struct Inner {
   };
};

int main() {
   Outer<int>::Inner<w> f;
}
```

So is it a g++ bug or am I missing something important about non-type variadic template parameters expansion which does not apply to class template parameters expansion?

Comment: "internal compiler error" clearly means a bug in GCC, regardless this is valid C++ or not.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that...

Comment: What does syntax `template <Tag<Ts> &...> struct Inner{};` mean?

Comment: @Zereges you're probably familiar with the concept of templates - parametrising types with some other types e.g. `template <class T> struct X {};`. Apart from types types can be parameterized by non-type value e.g. `template <int N> struct X {} ;`.  There are certain rules on what can be the value of non-type template parameter. One of possibilities is the reference to a static variable. This syntax provide a way to set the types of certain references templated static variables.

Comment: @W.F. I know about templates and that they can be paramatrized by value, but didn't know about that references to static variables.

Comment: @Zereges actually you can parametrize template with reference/pointer to a method as well, this can be a little bit more useful but in some cases references to static variables can also do some tricks :)

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer but someone might be interested)

Possible relatively simple workaround for GCC:

```
template <int>
struct Tag { };

Tag<0> w;

template <class... Ts>
struct OuterParent {
   template <Ts&...>
   struct Inner {
   };
};

template <int... Is>
struct Outer:OuterParent<Tag<Is>...> {
};

int main() {
   Outer<0>::Inner<w> f;
}
```